# How to create and fill a list of arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have the field "listofRows":

```
private List<String[]> listOfRows;
```

This list is supposed to hold several string arrays.

I then read in a line from a csv file, split the line into separate parts (using the commas as separators) and save the resulting strings in a string array:

```
String[] stringArray = line.split(",");
```

According to the debugger, the array stringArray now holds the two words from the CSV-file ("test" and "one").

The problem is with the next line of code:

```
listOfRows.add(stringArray);
```

This line does not work. 
I can't add the array to the list.

How can I add an array to an arraylist?

NB: I know how I could add the elements of an array to a list separately. This question has already been answered on StackOverflow. 
However, I want to add the array as a whole (!).
That is, every element of the list is supposed to be an array.

Comment: Can you please clarify `does not work`? *How* does it not work?

Comment: can you share the code? or clarify the question

Comment: Why do you want to mix Collections and Arrays -- it just confuses life. Can you not just convert the `String[]` to a `List<String>` and then handle `List<List<String>>`? I think you'll find things easier.

Comment: Logically it should work can you please mention what exact issue you are facing

Comment: @KevinO is right you can go ahead with that ? or you can add it as an arrylist of objects

Comment: You also need to instantiate your `listOfRows` to something other than `List`, for instance an `ArrayList`. `private List<String[]> listOfRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

Comment: I tested this code and no issues.  List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
     list.add(new String[]{"hello", "world"});

Comment: I think I got the problem ... I didn't instantiate the list ...

Comment: Thank you John for pointing that out

Comment: let me test it  again ...

Comment: Ok it works now ... thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your list:

`private List<String[]> listOfRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

Answer (score 1):

In constructor initialize your list and return unmodified list to outside

```
 public CSVReader(){
            this.br = null;
            this.line = "";
            this.splitSign = ",";
    listOfRows =new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the list or else you will get null pointer exception

```
  public CSVReader(){
                this.br = null;
                this.line = "";
                this.splitSign = ",";
                listOfRows =new ArrayList<>(); //Initialization
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your List and then add the string array to it.

```
private List<String[]> listOfRows = new List<String[]>();
ListOfRows.add(stringArray);
```

This would work without throwing any error such as Null pointer: not initialized.